# jquery validation not working with php and on.keyUp() event

Tags: php, jquery

I am working with **jQuery validation**, but I am facing a problem with `on.keyUp()` event.

Please review my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.
Here is my jQuery code which also contains PHP for some specific path.

**edited :** used # instead . at line $("#usernametxt").keyup(function()

```js
<input type="text" id="usernametxt">
<div id="ex_username"></div>


<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#usernametxt").keyup(function(){
      var user_name = $(this).val();
      var regex ='/^[a-z0-9_]{4,15}$/';
      var regex2='/^[a-z0-9_]{1,15}$/';
      
      if(user_name.length==0)
      {
        $("#ex_username").html("");
      }
      else if(user_name.length>15)
      {
        $("#ex_username").html("<img height='17px' style='margin-bottom:-3px;' width='17px' src='<?=base_url()?>assets/images/sign-warning-icon.png'> User Name Too Long.");
      }
      else if(user_name.length<4)
      {
        if(regex2.test(user_name) != true && user_name.length<4)
        {
          $("#ex_username").html("<img height='17px' style='margin-bottom:-3px;' width='17px' src='<?=base_url()?>assets/images/sign-warning-icon.png'> Only _ (Underscore) allowed.);
        }
        else
        {
          $("#ex_username").html("<img height='17px' style='margin-bottom:-3px;' width='17px' src='<?=base_url()?>assets/images/sign-warning-icon.png'> User Name Too Short.");
        }
      }
      else if(regex2.test(user_name) != true && user_name.length>=4)
      {
        $("#ex_username").html("<img height='17px' style='margin-bottom:-3px;' width='17px' src='<?=base_url()?>assets/images/sign-warning-icon.png'> Only _ (Underscore) allowed.");
      }
      else if(regex.test(user_name))
      {
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "existing_username",
          data:'user_name='+$(this).val(),
          success: function(data){
            $("#ex_username").html(data);
          }
        });
      }
      else
      {
        $("#ex_username").html("<img height='17px' style='margin-bottom:-3px;' width='17px' src='<?=base_url()?>assets/images/sign-check-icon.png'> Invalid username.");
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try change this line:

```
$(".usernametxt").keyup(function(){
```

for this line:

```
$("#usernametxt").keyup(function(){
```

See that, when you put a "id" attribute in a tag, jQuery identify this tag using "#" instead "." (this is used to identify a specific class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have included jQuery library before using jQuery events. Include jQuery library at top first and then use your code

**Incldue following CDN jQuery Library Link**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

and then write your jQuery validation code like :

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#usernametxt").keyup(function(){
             /*write your logic here*/
         });
     });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a `.` instead of a `#`, As Ramones mentionned, you should target the `id`.

But you also miss a `"` to close the string after the first `Only _ (Underscore) allowed.);`

Then your regular expression must not be wrapped with `'`. Those aren't strings.

And finally, you should clear the validation message (and hide the image) at start of the function. That would make sure that there is no message if there is no error.

How to debug all that by yourself? Use the [**console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers/77337#77337). At least, you will have an error message (not always clear tho.) and the line number where it occurs.

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/EwVXYE?editors=1011). The validation messages are "jumpy" because of the missing images.